# multiple condition checks on grails domain constraints?

Tags: grails

For a domain such as

```
class Question {

    String questionText
    Type questionType

    static hasMany = [choices: Option]          
}
```

I was wondering if this type of conditional constraint is possible. I want the constraint to be such that if the `questionType` is either (radio, checkbox, dropdown) and (&&) `choices.size() == 0`then constraint is violated and error is thrown. I know the second part of the condition i.e. to check size of collection can be done with size parameter but I was wondering if we can have complex conditions like above i.e. multiple conditions checks with && operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need custom validator. Something like below should do the job. Take a look at [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html#constraints) - it's quite convenient.

```
static constraints = {
    questionType validator: { val, obj -> 
        !(val in [Type.Radio, Type.Checkbox, Type.Dropdown] && obj.choices.isEmpty()) 
    }
}
```

But then you'll get error message generated by grails. It's good to provide more readable validation error. You can return custom message code and define it in `messages.properties`:

```
static constraints = {
    questionType validator: { val, obj -> 
        if (val in [Type.Radio, Type.Checkbox, Type.Dropdown] && obj.choices.isEmpty())         
            return 'emptyChoicesErrorMessage'
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if You can just: return `val in [Type.Radio, Type.Checkbox, Type.Dropdown] && obj.choices.isEmpty()`?

Comment: @Opal: Good point! I'm accustomed to writing validators like that because in most cases I need to return custom message code :) I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I just don't like all the if constructs and try to eliminate them if possible.

Comment: Me too, but in some cases traditional if construct seems to be more readable in my opinion. Take a look at second example, short version would be: `(val in [Type.Radio, Type.Checkbox, Type.Dropdown] && obj.choices.isEmpty()) ? 'emptyChoicesErrorMessage' : false`. It's not so nice :)

Comment: Sorry, `(val in [Type.Radio, Type.Checkbox, Type.Dropdown] && obj.choices.isEmpty()) ? 'emptyChoicesErrorMessage' : true`